# Scaleable Background for SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I have a large background and am currently using texture atlasing to display it (It's 2000x2000). This works great, however when I scale the node out to a certain extent, black space appears like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/06fM7.jpg

I used the following code to scale it (With map being the node variable):

```
map.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.1, duration: 2))
```

So with all this in mind, is there a way to make it *not* show that black space? Instead of showing the black space it will simply tile the image so it doesn't show?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, are you trying to scale the image down to a smaller size, but yet it will fill the whole screen?

Comment: There's no need for a texture atlas if your image is 2000 by 2000.

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to scale the image down, but when it gets to a certain point in which scaling it down makes it not fit the screen, it will place a second image next to it so it gives the effect of one large image.

And I though texture atlas's make loading the image faster? If not I'll just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background is just repeated squares, isn't it? Instead of having one 2000 x 2000 you could have 100 items of 200 x 200 tiles. Am I correct?

If so, you can add those evenly spread out 100 tiles to an parent SKNode, and you can then scale that parent node. If you want to scale out even more I guess you need to add more tiles to that SKNode.

As an optimization, you can replace 10 x 10 tiles with only one tile with another texture, but that's only an optimization. Don't do that unless you have to.

Comment: This is what I was originally wanting to do (And that's how I originally designed the image -- As a 150x150 square), however I didn't know how to implement it properly. How would I spread them out evenly?

Comment: If the tiles are 200 wide I guess you want to place them at (-100, -100), (-100, 100), (100, 100), (100, -100) — in a four tile example..